# jQuery actions strictly after full DOM load

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader

I'm using [jquerynewsticker](http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/) to reveal 100,000 digits of the number π in a news ticker fashion.
If i have my Chrome inspector open, i can see that the page loads from top to bottom, but the  after the number, as well all the JS behind it, is rendered black for a few seconds, and only then becomes coloured as per default. However, the script already starts running as you can see on the test page here: http://marckremers.com/pi/ticker/
It seems to run, but without rendering.
If i reduce the size of the number, it works.
So it's clearly an issue where the loading isnt complete.

How can I force the script to only play once everything has 100% loaded?

Comment: Have you tried `jquery(window).load()` instead of `jquery(document).ready()`?

Comment: I was just going to suggest what Jason did. `$(document).load(...)` is the same as `<body onload="">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your website I see the you load the ticker plugin and you execute your own code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $(function () {
        $('#js-news').ticker({
            speed: 0.05,
            fadeInSpeed: 0,
            titleText: '',
            controls: false,
        });
    });
});
```

There 2 issues in this code:

1) Unnecessary nesting. you execute your code on document ready and then you call again a document ready handler ($(function(){...});

Keep in mind that writing $(document).ready( function(){} ) or $(function(){}) serves exactly the same purpose. For this reason you can remove the second event listener (useless):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#js-news').ticker({
        speed: 0.05,
        fadeInSpeed: 0,
        titleText: '',
        controls: false,
    });
});
```

with document.ready registration your code will run after the DOM has been completely built.

2) Another issue I see is that your selector #js-news does not resolve! I see no element in the page with ID=js-news... am I missing something ?

Comment: I just removed the on document ready bit, still no luck. Yes the id is there, above all the numbers, it's the <ul>. Thanks

Comment: I put it on jsfiddle so it's easy for everyone to have a look. here's the link to the editor http://jsfiddle.net/Wcn5v/1/ and here you can see the jsfiddle example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Wcn5v/1/show/

Comment: true that does seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Wcn5v/2/ with 100,000 chars :-) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can put your code as above to wait for the dom to be fully loaded.

```
$(function() {
    // Your code
});
```

If it's not enough, if you want to wait for everything to be loaded (images, css, ...), you can put your code as above :

```
$(function()
{
    $(window).bind('load', function()
    {
        // Your code
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope it does the exact same thing i'm afraid.